# Why do rootkits only attack 32 bit systems?

Tags: operating-systems, 32-bit, malware

Title says it all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because coders target 32-bit systems as they are the most commonly used desktop architecture. A 64-bit variant could be (and probably already has been) made. It's like the age old question of why there are more viruses for Windows based systems. You'd be foolish to not code for the most popular systems out there if you had malicious intent.

Comment: What does marketing and virii have in common?  They usually like to target the largest demographic. :)

Comment: haha, you're exactly right :)

Answer (score 2):

The apocryphal quote comes to mind, supposedly said by Willie Sutton (he never actually said it, but ignoring that), when asked why he robbed banks: "Because that's where the money is".